Hilbert basis theorem implies $F[x, y]$ is a UFD
A professor casually mentioned to me that if $F$ is a field, then $F[x, y]$ is a unique factorization domain by the Hilbert basis theorem. This is not clear to me. It's obvious that if $0 \neq p(x, y) \in F[x, y]$, then $p(x, y)$ can be factored into finitely many irreducibles. So I guess the Hilbert basis theorem must imply the uniqueness part. This is as far as I could get:
Let $I$ be the ideal generated by all irreducibles dividing $p(x, y)$. Then by the Hilbert basis theorem, $I$ is finitely generated. So, $p(x, y)$ admits finitely many factorizations into irreducibles.
This is a bit closer to uniqueness, but how do we get from finitely many factorizations to a unique factorization?


Hilbert's Basis Theorem can only say that $F[x,y]$ is a noetherian ring.

That $F[x,y]$ is a UFD follows from the statement that, "$R$ is a UFD $\Rightarrow$ $R[x]$ is also a UFD", by applying it to the UFD $R=F[x]$ and note that $F[x,y]\cong (F[x])[y]$, the latter being the polynomial ring over $F[x]$ which is UFD by the statement I quoted.
That "$R$ is a UFD $\Rightarrow$ $R[x]$ is also a UFD" is proved in, say, Abstract Algebra by Pierre Antoine Grillet, Theorem $10.4$ in Chapter III.

Some students may wonder the relationship between "noetherian domains" and UFDs.
In fact neither condition implies the other:
$\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a noetherian domain which is not a UFD,
and $F[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n,\cdots]$, the polynomial ring with countably infinitely many intermediates over a field, is a non-noetherian UFD.


